Estimation under uncertainity
I am the owner of a unique event venue—a historic mansion—that can be rented out for weddings, corporate events, and other exclusive functions. Due to the nature of such events, my venue can only host one booking per day. I am trying to determine the optimal pricing strategy to maximize my expected revenue.
Here's my situation:

Market Data:

I have access to extensive market data from other event venues in my area, including their pricing and occupancy rates.
This data provides insights into the average booking probabilities at different price points and general price elasticity within the market.
For example, I know the average booking rate for venues similar to mine is around 40% per day, with variations depending on the season, day of the week, and pricing.


Own Booking Data:

Since my venue is relatively new, I have limited own booking data—covering the past few months.
For each date, I know whether my venue was booked (binary outcome: booked or not booked) and the price I offered.
Given that I can only host one event per day, the data is sparse and consists of individual binary observations per day.



What I've Tried:
To integrate the market data with my own booking data, I've attempted the following Bayesian approach:

Modeling the Booking Probability:

I modeled the market booking probability using a Beta distribution, with parameters estimated from the market occupancy rates and number of venues.
For my own booking probability, I used a Binomial likelihood based on my observed bookings.


Bayesian Updating:

I used the Beta distribution from the market data as a prior and updated it with my own booking data to obtain the posterior distribution for my venue's booking probability.
However, because the market data encompasses many venues and dates (thus leading to large prior parameters), my limited own data (only one possible booking per day) contributes minimally to the posterior.
As a result, the posterior booking probability remains heavily influenced by the prior, not reflecting my venue's unique performance.


Adjusting Prior Influence:

To give more weight to my own data, I considered adjusting the prior's effective sample size (( N_0 )) by scaling down the prior parameters.
However, I'm unsure how to justify this adjustment statistically and whether it's appropriate in my context.



Challenges:

Dominant Prior: The extensive market data leads to a prior that overpowers my own observations when forming the posterior distribution.
Sparse Own Data: My own booking data is limited and consists of binary outcomes, making it difficult for the model to accurately reflect my venue's booking probability.
Justifying Prior Adjustment: Adjusting ( N_0 ) without a principled basis may compromise the statistical validity of the model.

How can I solve above 3 challenges?

If your livelihood depends on this, unless you have a considerable background in statistics, it would seem advisable to consult with a skilled statistician or data scientist.
